# given n-2 equivalence classes and no equivalence classes contains exactly 3 elements, how many elements are there in the equivalence relation R

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $A$ such that $\mid A\mid\geq4$, say that we have an equivalence relation $R$ on the set of elements in $A$. If there are exactly $n-2$ equivalence classes (where $n=\mid A \mid$) and no equivalence classes contains exactly $3$ elements, how many elements are there in set $R$.

Comment: Does $|A|=n$? ..

Comment: Yea, forgot to add that

Comment: OK, I figured ...  so in terms of the partition of elements, what must be the case? How can you partition n elements into n-2 groups without getting a group of 3?

Comment: You could put them in pairs and then if n is odd one element goes by itself.

Comment: That doesn't work ... say $n=6$ ... then putting them in pairs you get $3$ groups, but you need $4$ groups. Try again ...

Comment: We could have two pairs of elements and then the remaining elements would go by themselves. So for a pair of elements (a,b) that form an equivalence class, there are 4 equivalence relations (a,a) (b,b) (a,b) (b,a). So we get 2*4+(n-4). Is this logic correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct! Well done :)